# Java3d scenegraph visualization tool

Tags: java-3d, scenegraph

Is there a tool for visualizing a given java3d app's scenegraph? Just like there is tools for auto generating UML diagrams.

Edit: if not, is there any good free tools for drawing such graphs? os x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

J3DWorkbench is very good. http://eclectic3d.net/

Comment: thank you, even though its quite a while since i asked the question, it might still come in handy for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

this Java 3D forum thread might help: http://www.java.net/forum/topic/javadesktop/java-desktop-technologies/java-3d/java3d-loaded-scene-info

August